# Best way to edit files through FTP client and save a backup automatically

Tags: github, ftp

It is a habit that I have for editing files online . As far as I have many working websites and I don't want to backup all the files located on them but only those that I have edited through FTP client software .

What is the best way to have a version tracker for files ? Something like Github

I am not cool with editing files (websites) on localhost and move them to online mode. I am looking for a way to synchronize both local and web files in order to have the latest version of special files.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something like WinSCP or setting up XAMPP and working locally pushing to bitbuckket or github then once done working uploading all the files through FTP. WinSCP is for windows and allows you to edit the files without having to download them, edit them, reupload them. It allows you to edit them while they are live. However, XAMPP way is a better way to go if you plan to work on other peoples websites at any point in time.